# How to have two different border stroke color for textfield-ios

Tags: ios, uitextfield, stroke

In our app we wanted to have 2 different border colors around textfields (eg: top and left edge in 1 color, and bottom and right edge in another color)
-Is this possible? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's **no pre-built way to have different colors** for each border side, but **you can fake it with layers**. Probably more work than it's worth, but basically what you want to do is draw individual calayers for each border, then add them to the textfield.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> //This goes up top, but you already know that :-)

CALayer *topBorder = [CALayer layer];
topBorder.frame = // cgrect of where you want the bottom border. Use the textfields frame as reference, but treat the border as a solid rectangle
topBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor; // the .CGColor is important, don't forget it

[toScrollView.layer addSublayer:topBorder];
```

Then just rinse and repeat for each side. You can even set the dominant color normally, then just add the sides that differ (less work)